# Parsing JSON (from select database) using Volley

Tags: json, android-volley

I try to parsing data from my database and show it on listview. However since in logcat does't show what error volley does, I don't know how to solve it. Here's my code:

**JsonResult**

```
{"result":[{"namaBarang":"kabel","jumlahBarang":"5","tglKel":"2018-06-06"},{"namaBarang":"optical power meter","jumlahBarang":"5","tglKel":"0000-00-00"}]}
```

From that json result, I try to parse it with *JsonObject*, and here's what my *JsonObject* looks like.

**Activity**

> ```
>    JsonObjectRequest bkRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, >url, null ,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
>             try {
>                 JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("result");
>                 BarangKeluar bk = new BarangKeluar();
>                 bk.setNamaBarang(obj.getString("namaBarang"));
>                 bk.setJumlahBarang(obj.getString("jumlahBarang"));
>                 bk.setTglBarang(obj.getString("tglBarang"));
>                 bkList.add(bk) ;
>             } catch (JSONException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>             // notifying list adapter about data changes
>             // so that it renders the list view with updated data
>             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
>         }
>     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
>             VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
>         }
>     });
>     // Adding request to request queue
>     AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(bkRequest);
> ```

But after I push it on my phone, the listview not populate with my json.

**UPDATE1**
Already trying to try pistolcaffe and IntelliJ Amiya code but still not working.

**Logcat**

> D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0 I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static:
>   isSBSettingEnabled false I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static:
>   isSBSettingEnabled false D/AbsListView:  onsize change  D/Volley: [1]
>   2.onErrorResponse: AppController

But my AppController work fine with [This](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/) this tutorial.

Marked threads duplicate in [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android/) threads. I look up on this and the difference is most of answer use HttpConnection.

---

#### Solved

Finally, I fixed this.

Here's the code after fix.

**Activity**

> ```
> //Create JsonObjectRequest
> JsonObjectRequest bkRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,new
> Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
>         @Override
>         public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
>             Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
>
>             try {
>                 JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray("result");
>                 for(int i=0;i< obj.length();i++) {
>                     JSONObject json     = obj.getJSONObject(i);
>                     BarangKeluar bk = new BarangKeluar();
>                     bk.setNamaBarang(json.getString("namaBarang"));
>                     bk.setJumlahBarang(json.getString("jumlahBarang"));
>                     bk.setTglBarang(json.getString("tglKel"));
>
>                     //Adding data into array
>                     bkList.add(bk);
>                 }
>
>             } catch (JSONException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>                 e.getMessage();
>             }
>             // notifying list adapter about data changes
>             // so that it renders the list view with updated data
>             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
>
>         }
>     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
>             VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
>         }
>     });
>     // Adding request to request queue
>     AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(bkRequest);
> ```

Comment: Hey @Nilesh Rathod , i do lookup on similar thread, and most of the answer given were httpcon not a volley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expected Error is

> JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

- Your **`result`** is **`JSONArray`**.
- No **`tglBarang`** *KEY* present. Set proper name.

**Don't**

```
JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("result");
```

**Do**

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("result");
```

**RECTIFIED CODE**

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("result");
   for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++)
   {
     JSONObject json     = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String namaBarang   = json.getString("namaBarang");
     String jumlahBarang = json.getString("jumlahBarang");
     String tglKel       = json.getString("tglKel");

            BarangKeluar bk = new BarangKeluar();
            bk.setNamaBarang(namaBarang);
            bk.setJumlahBarang(jumlahBarang);
            bk.setTglBarang(tglKel);
            bkList.add(bk) 
   }
```

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild and Run`.

Comment: do i need to change my  **JsonObjectRequest** method into **JsonArrayRequest**? i do try this answer, and still not work somehow.

Answer (score 1):

you missied JSONArray and "tglBarang" -> "tglKel"

```
    JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray("result");
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
        String namaBarang = obj.getJSONObject(i).getString("namaBarang");
        String jumlahBarang = obj.getJSONObject(i).getString("jumlahBarang");
        String tglKel = obj.getJSONObject(i).getString("tglKel");
    }
```

Comment: already tried ur code and @IntelliJ Amiya code, both still not working. Do i need to change my method instead into JsonArrayRequest ?